# Is there such thing as a plain text html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to change a word in a sentence. I can change the contents of tags easily enough but they always come with their innate behaviour. e.g. `<b>` makes text **bold**  `<p>` moves down to a new line 
etc.

What I want is to do something like this?

```
<text> Static part of sentence </text> <text id="placeholder"> Text to 
     ToUpdate </text>
```

I thought `<plaintext>` or `<pre>` might be the way to go but `<plaintext>` is depreciated and `<pre>` still starts the text on a new line.

Comment: `<span>`, the `<div>` of inline elements

Comment: Why so many down votes? What was wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `span` tag

```js
document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = "I HAVE CHANGED!";
})
```

```html
<span>Static part of sentence </span><span id="placeholder"> Text to ToUpdate</span>

<button id="update">Update the text</button>
```

The span tag allows you to group inline-elements in a document and it has no visual effects as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).